# How to get past "pending" when installing an IME?

Tags: windows-10, ime

A (non-admin) user added a Chinese IME (zn-tw) but then couldn't use different fonts in Office365, (because that language pack hadn't been installed) so they removed it thinking that it needed to be done by an admin for it to be "fully" installed.

Now, they want to re-install the IME (or *any* IME), and it just sits there, endlessly "pending...".  It doesn't matter what IME, and -- oddly -- it doesn't matter what user profile, and it doesn't matter if it is added via the GUI or PoSh.  "pending..." always "pending..."

I see lots of other posts about IMEs being stuck at "downloading...", but those fixes haven't done anything for this.  It's frustrating that it absolutely did work previously, so it can't be a GP setting.  It appears to be system-wide (tested adding an IME as Admin), yet everything else is working great.

This machine is running Win10 20H2.  Any suggestions on how to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it manually:

- Run Command Prompt as Administrator
- Enter the following command:

  ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Language.Basic~~~zn-TW~0.0.1.0
  ```